# What is save_weights_only parameter in tf.keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint?

Tags: python, tensorflow

In tensorflow's documentation, the description of `save_weights_only` parameter of ModelCheckpoint is as follows:

> if True, then only the model's weights will be saved (model.save_weights(filepath)), else the full model is saved (model.save(filepath)).

What does it mean by "the full model is saved"? I know that we use `model.load_weights('path/to/model')` when `save_weights_only=True`. But what's different when it's False? I.e. what additional information is saved besides the weights? And how can we load this "full model"? Do we still need to define its layers and compile it before loading the saved model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the [source code](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/v2.10.0/keras/callbacks.py#L1522) for `ModelCheckpoint` you can see that when `save_weights_only=True` you are actually calling `model.save_weights()` where model is an instance of `tf.keras.Model`. Checking the docs for the difference between [`model.save_weights`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save_weights) and [`model.save`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#save), we are pointed to keras' [serialization and saving](https://keras.io/guides/serialization_and_saving/) guide. Here it explains that whole model saving and loading entails:

- The model's architecture/config.
- The model's weight values.
- The model's compilation information.
- The optimizer and its state, if any.